# Nginx https proxy pass - zanata

Tags: nginx, proxy, zanata

i have a central reverse proxy with nginx, and inside of my environment i have a unified development tool like this:

dev.mycompany.com.br

and some applications like jenkins, artifactory.. working very well

dev.mycompany.com.br/jenkins
dev.mycompany.com.br/artifactory

but now i tryed to add another application (zanata) working in my docker server listening in following address: http://192.168.4.240:8080/zanata

in dev.conf in my nginx server i added the follow configuration for reverse proxy:

location /zanata {
        proxy_pass              http://192.168.4.240:8080/zanata/;

but returns blank page and 404 http code in access log.

if i remove /zanata like this:

proxy_pass http://192.168.4.240:8080/;

working fine and go to the wildfly welcome page.

somebody have a idea for this work this configuration?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think yo use https on top of your proxy and when zanata redirect it replaces the protocol by http.

curl -vvv https://myserver.com/zanata to see that.

edit your proxy to redirect http to https and it should work.
something like this :

```
server {
  listen         80;`
  server_name    myserver.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```